# OS not moving on to next section

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

After fixing any errors when compiling using NASM, the program now completes the first section but when it reaches the second section it does nothing. I am trying to combine two guides to create one.
The second section starts when it says ;CALCULATOR CODE STARTS HERE

I am new to this Assembly Language so I have no idea how to fix it. If you can help it would be greatly appreciated. If you can just have the code written out in your answer to make it easier for me that would be appreciated as well :)

```
[bits 16]           ; tell assembler that working in real mode(16 bit mode)
[org 0x7c00]        ; organize from 0x7C00 memory location where BIOS will load us

start:              ; start label from where our code starts

    xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
    mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
    mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
    mov bx,0x8000

    mov ax,0x13         ;clears the screen
    int 0x10            ;call bios video interrupt

    mov ah,02           ;clear the screen with big font
    int 0x10            ;interrupt display

    ;set cursor to specific position on screen
    mov ah,0x02         ; set value for change to cursor position
    mov bh,0x00         ; page
    mov dh,0x06         ; y cordinate/row
    mov dl,0x09         ; x cordinate/col
    int 0x10

    mov si, start_os_intro              ; point start_os_intro string to source index
    call _print_DiffColor_String        ; call print different color string function

    ;set cursor to specific position on screen
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x10
    mov dl,0x06
    int 0x10

    mov si,press_key                    ; point press_key string to source index
    call _print_GreenColor_String       ; call print green color string function

    mov ax,0x00         ; get keyboard input
    int 0x16            ; interrupt for hold & read input

    ;/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ; load second sector into memory

    mov ah, 0x02                    ; load second stage to memory
    mov al, 1                       ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
    mov dl, 0x80                    ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
    mov ch, 0                       ; cylinder number
    mov dh, 0                       ; head number
    mov cl, 2                       ; sector number
    mov bx, _OS_Stage_2             ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
    int 0x13                        ; disk I/O interrupt

    jmp _OS_Stage_2                 ; jump to second stage


    ;/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ; declaring string datas here
    start_os_intro db 'Welcome to My OS!',0
    press_key db '>>>> Press any key <<<<',0

    login_username db 'Username : ',0
    login_password db 'Password : ',0

    display_text db '! Welcome to my Operating System !', 0

    os_info db 10, 'My Operating System, 16-Bit, version=1.0.0',13,0

    press_key_2 db 10,'Press any key to go to graphics view',0

    window_text db 10,'Graphics in OS......', 0
    hello_world_text db 10,10, '    Hello World!',0
    login_label db '#] Login please....(ESC to skip login)', 0


    ;/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ; defining printing string functions here

    ;****** print string without color

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; value to tell interrupt handler that take value from al & print it

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb                ; get character from string
    cmp al, 0                    ; cmp al with end of string
    je .done_print               ; if char is zero, end of string
    int 0x10                     ; otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat_next_char        ; jmp to .repeat_next_char if not 0

.done_print:
    ret                         ;return

;****** print string with different colors

_print_DiffColor_String:
        mov bl,1                ;color value
    mov ah, 0x0E

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done_print
    add bl,6               ;increase color value by 6
    int 0x10
    jmp .repeat_next_char

.done_print:
    ret

;****** print string with green color

_print_GreenColor_String:
    mov bl,10
    mov ah, 0x0E

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done_print
    int 0x10
    jmp .repeat_next_char

.done_print:
    ret

;****** print string with white color

_print_WhiteColor_String:
    mov bl,15
    mov ah, 0x0E

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done_print
    int 0x10
    jmp .repeat_next_char

.done_print:
    ret

;****** print string with yellow color

_print_YellowColor_String:
    mov bl,14
    mov ah, 0x0E

.repeat_next_char:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done_print
    int 0x10
    jmp .repeat_next_char

.done_print:
    ret


    ;///////////////////////////////////////////
    ; boot loader magic number
    times ((0x200 - 2) - ($ - $$)) db 0x00     ;set 512 bytes for boot sector which are necessary
    dw 0xAA55                                  ; boot signature 0xAA & 0x55


;////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

_OS_Stage_2 :

    mov al,2                    ; set font to normal mode
    mov ah,0                    ; clear the screen
    int 0x10                    ; call video interrupt

    mov cx,0                    ; initialize counter(cx) to get input

    ;***** print login_label on screen
    ;set cursor to specific position on screen
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x00
    mov dl,0x00
    int 0x10

    mov si,login_label              ; point si to login_username
    call print_string               ; display it on screen

    ;****** read username

    ;set cursor to specific position on screen
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x02
    mov dl,0x00
    int 0x10

    mov si,login_username          ; point si to login_username
    call print_string              ; display it on screen

_getUsernameinput:

    mov ax,0x00             ; get keyboard input
    int 0x16                ; hold for input

    cmp ah,0x1C             ; compare input is enter(1C) or not
    je .exitinput           ; if enter then jump to exitinput

    cmp ah,0x01             ; compare input is escape(01) or not
    je _skipLogin           ; jump to _skipLogin

    mov ah,0x0E             ;display input char
    int 0x10

    inc cx                  ; increase counter
    cmp cx,5                ; compare counter reached to 5
    jbe _getUsernameinput   ; yes jump to _getUsernameinput
    jmp .inputdone          ; else jump to inputdone

.inputdone:
    mov cx,0                ; set counter to 0
    jmp _getUsernameinput   ; jump to _getUsernameinput
    ret                     ; return

.exitinput:
    hlt


    ;****** read password

    ;set x y position to text
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x03
    mov dl,0x00
    int 0x10

    mov si,login_password               ; point si to login_username
    call print_string                   ; display it on screen

_getPasswordinput:

    mov ax,0x00
    int 0x16

    cmp ah,0x1C
    je .exitinput

    cmp ah,0x01
    je _skipLogin

    inc cx

    cmp cx,5
    jbe _getPasswordinput

    jmp .inputdone

.inputdone:
    mov cx,0
    jmp _getPasswordinput
    ret
.exitinput:
    hlt

;****** display display_text on screen

    ;set x y position to text
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x08
    mov dl,0x12
    int 0x10

    mov si, display_text        ;display display_text on screen
    call print_string

    ;set x y position to text
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x9
    mov dl,0x10
    int 0x10

    mov si, os_info     ;display os_info on screen
    call print_string

    ;set x y position to text
    mov ah,0x02
    mov bh,0x00
    mov dh,0x11
    mov dl,0x11
    int 0x10

    mov si, press_key_2     ;display press_key_2 on screen
    call print_string

    mov ah,0x00
    int 0x16


;//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

_skipLogin:

    ;/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ; load third sector into memory

    mov ah, 0x03                    ; load third stage to memory
    mov al, 1
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov ch, 0
    mov dh, 0
    mov cl, 3                       ; sector number 3
    mov bx, _OS_Stage_3
    int 0x13

    jmp _OS_Stage_3

;////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

_OS_Stage_3:

    mov ax,0x13              ; clears the screen
    int 0x10

;CALCULATOR CODE STARTS HERE

  ;******************************************
  ; jumping from rel mode to protected mode
  ; by using disk interrupt

  mov ah, 0x02        ; load second stage to memory
  mov al, 0x10        ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
  mov dl, 0x80        ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
  mov ch, 0           ; cylinder number
  mov dh, 0           ; head number
  mov cl, 2           ; sector number
  mov bx, _start      ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
  int 0x13            ; disk I/O interrupt

  ; before jumping clearing all interrupts
  cli

  ; jump to protected mode
  jmp _start                 ; jump to second stage

  times 1024 - ($-$$) db 0x00     ;set 1024 bytes for boot sector which are necessary
  dw 0xAA55                          ; boot signature 0xAA & 0x55


; bootloader code end

;******************************************
; x86 code begin 

_start:

main :

  ;******************************************
  ; set base pointer to heap
  ; and stack pointer to stack for functions and variables
  mov ebp, __HEAP__
  mov esp, __STACK__

  ; clear the screen
  call clear_screen

  ; set cursor mosition
  mov dword[X], 25
  mov dword[Y], 0
  push dword[X]
  push dword[Y]
  call goto_xy
  add esp, 8

  ; print os message
  mov esi, os_msg
  call print_string

  call print_new_line

  call print_new_line

  ; display the calculator menu
  call display_menu

;*************************************************
; this loop continue until valid coice is selected
.read_loop:

  ; read choice
  call read_single_key

  ; assign choice to choice variable
  mov ah, byte[KEYCODE]
  mov byte[choice], ah

  ; if other entry is entered continue to loop
  call read_single_key

  mov ah, byte[KEYCODE]
  cmp ah, byte[DELETE_KEY]
  je main

  ; if enter key is pressed jump to perform_calulation
  mov ah, byte[KEYCODE]
  cmp ah, byte[ENTER_KEY]
  je perform_operation

  jmp .read_loop

  ret

;******************************************
; this function displays calc string menu
display_menu :
  push ebp

  mov esi, calc_msg
  call print_string

  call print_new_line
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, menu_str
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, addition_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, substraction_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, multiplication_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, division_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, modulus_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, logicaland_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, logicalor_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, clear_screen_menu
  call print_string  

  call print_new_line
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, select_choice_str
  call print_string  

  pop ebp
  ret

;***********************************************
; this function read bytes of data from keyboard
; by converting it into dword
perform_operation :

  ; if choice = clear screen(8)
  ; get choice
  mov al, byte[choice]
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_8]
  je perform_clear_screen

  call print_new_line

  ; read first number bytes
  mov esi, enter_first_number
  call print_string  

  call read_data

  ; check all read bytes are numerics in BUFFER
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call check_all_bytes_are_numeric
  add esp, 4

  cmp eax, 0
  je .not_numerics

  ; convert bytes array into dword
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call bytes_length
  add esp, 4

  push ebx
  push eax
  call byte_array_to_dword
  add esp, 8

  ; assign read dword to number_1
  mov dword[number_1], eax

  ; read second number
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, enter_second_number
  call print_string  

  call read_data

  ; check all read bytes are numerics in BUFFER
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call check_all_bytes_are_numeric
  add esp, 4

  cmp eax, 0
  je .not_numerics

  ; convert bytes array into dword
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call bytes_length
  add esp, 4

  push ebx
  push eax
  call byte_array_to_dword
  add esp, 8

  ; assign read dword to number_2
  mov dword[number_2], eax

  ; once reading numbers done, 
  ; jump to operation by choice function
  jmp perform_operation_by_choice

; when not numerics then display eror message
; and reload screen
.not_numerics :
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, error_msg
  call print_string

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;****************************************************
; this function check the entered choice by keycodes,
; such as addition, substraction and jump to
; that specific procedure
perform_operation_by_choice :

  ; get choice
  mov al, byte[choice]

  ; if addition
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_1]
  je perform_addition

  ; if substraction
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_2]
  je perform_substraction

  ; if multiplication
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_3]
  je perform_multiplication

  ; if division
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_4]
  je perform_division

  ; if modulus
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_5]
  je perform_modulus

  ; if logical and
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_6]
  je perform_logical_and

  ; if logical or
  cmp al, byte[KEYCODE_7]
  je perform_logical_or

  ; if other
  ; then display invalid choice message
  call print_new_line
  mov esi, invalid_choice_str
  call print_string

  call reload_screen

  ret

;****************************
; call clear screen 
; and then reload screen
; to reload calc menu
perform_clear_screen :
  call clear_screen

  call reload_screen

  ret

;******************************************
; this function jumps to main
reload_screen :

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, reload_screen_msg
  call print_string

  call read_single_key

  jmp main

;******************************************
; this function gets two numbers add them
; and stores the result in result variable
perform_addition :

  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  add eax, ebx
  mov dword[result], eax

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, addition
  call print_string

  ; convert dword to byte array
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  ; print byte array
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;**********************************************
; this function gets two numbers substract them
; and stores the result in result variable
perform_substraction :

  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  sub eax, ebx
  mov dword[result], eax

  call print_new_line

  mov esi, substraction
  call print_string

  ; convert dword to byte array
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  ; print byte array
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;**********************************************
; this function gets two numbers multiply them
; and stores the result in result variable
; when performing multiplication
; if result goes out of dword boundry
; it saves in edx register
perform_multiplication :

  xor edx, edx
  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  mul ebx
  mov dword[result], eax

  ; print result
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, multiplication
  call print_string

  ; print result
  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;********************************************
; this function gets two numbers divide them
; and stores the result in result variable
perform_division :

  xor edx, edx
  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  div ebx
  mov dword[result], eax

  ; print result
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, division
  call print_string

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;**********************************************
; this function gets two numbers take mod of it
; and stores the result in result variable
perform_modulus :

  xor edx, edx
  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  div ebx
  mov dword[result], edx

  ; print result
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, modulus
  call print_string

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;***********************************
; this function and the two numbers
perform_logical_and :

  xor edx, edx
  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  and eax, ebx
  mov dword[result], eax

  ; print result
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, logicaland
  call print_string

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret
;***********************************
; this function or the two numbers
perform_logical_or :

  xor edx, edx
  mov eax, dword[number_1]
  mov ebx, dword[number_2]

  or eax, ebx
  mov dword[result], eax

  ; print result
  call print_new_line

  mov esi, logicalor
  call print_string

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push dword[result]
  push ebx
  call dword_to_byte_array
  add esp, 8

  lea ebx, [BUFFER]
  push ebx
  call print_byte_array
  add esp, 4

  call print_new_line

  call reload_screen

  ret

;*****************************************
; this function reads a single key
; stores character to KEYCHAR variable
; and keycode to KEYCODE variable
read_single_key :
  push ebp

  ; keyboard interrupt
    mov ax,0x00
    int 0x16

  mov byte[KEYCHAR], al
  mov byte[KEYCODE], ah

  ; display the entered character
    mov ah,0x0E
    int 0x10

  pop ebp
  ret

;**********************************************
; this function keep reading data until
; enter key is pressed
; it stores char data into global buffer BUFFER
read_data :
  push ebp

  mov ecx, 0

.input_keys_loop :

  ; keyboard interrupt
    mov ax,0x00
    int 0x16

  ; if enter key, jump to exit
    cmp ah, byte[ENTER_KEY]
    je .exitinput

  ; display entered character
    mov ah,0x0E
    int 0x10

  ; add it to buffer
  mov byte[BUFFER + ecx], al

  inc ecx

  jmp .input_keys_loop 

.exitinput:

  ; add null terminator in buffer  
  mov byte[BUFFER + ecx], 0x00

  pop ebp
    ret


;*********************************************
; this function removes everything from screen
; and set cursor location to (0,0)
clear_screen :
  mov ax,0x13
  mov al,2
    mov ah,0
    int 0x10

  mov byte[NEWLINE], 0

  ret


;******************************************

.next_char_loop :
  ; get character in al
    lodsb

    cmp al, 0
    je .exit

  int 0x10

  jmp .next_char_loop

.exit:
    ret

;******************************************
; this function print array of bytes
; param ebp - 8 = address of buffer
print_byte_array:

  mov ecx, 0
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 8]

.loop:
  cmp byte[ebx + ecx], 0
  je .exit
  ; get byte from buffer
  mov al, byte[ebx + ecx]
  mov ah, 0x0E
  int 0x10

  inc ecx

  jmp .loop

.exit:
  ret

;******************************************
; this function prints a single character
; param ebp - 8 = chracter
print_char :
  push ebp

  xor eax, eax
  mov eax, dword[ebp - 8]

  mov ah, 0x0E
  int 0x10

  pop ebp
  ret

;***************************************************
; this function checks all bytes are from range 0..9
check_all_bytes_are_numeric : 
  push ebp

  ; get BUFFER address
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 8]
  mov ecx, 0

.check_loop :
  cmp byte[ebx + ecx], 0
  je .exit

  ; if data is '0'
  cmp byte[ebx + ecx], 0x30
  jge .in_numeric

  mov eax, 0

  inc ecx

  jmp .check_loop

.in_numeric :

  ; if data is '9'
  cmp byte[ebx + ecx], 0x39
  jle .numeric

  mov eax, 0

  jmp .exit

.numeric :
  mov eax, 1
  inc ecx
  jmp .check_loop

.exit :
  pop ebp
  ret

;***************************************************
; this function gets each byte and multiply with 
; decimal position such as 1,10,100,1000,...
; and finally add with the result to get dword 
byte_array_to_dword : 
  push ebp

  ; get BUFFER address
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 8]

  mov dword[number], 0
  mov dword[decimal_pos], 1

  ; get digit count
  mov ecx, dword[ebp - 12]
  dec ecx

.convert_dword_loop :
  cmp ecx, 0
  jl .exit

  xor eax, eax
  xor edx, edx
  ; get original data
  ; character '1' = 0x31
  ; substract 0x30 from it  
  mov al, byte[ebx + ecx]
  sub al, 0x30

  push ebx

  ; clear ebx and edx for multiplication
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor edx, edx

  ; num * 1,10,100...
  mov ebx, dword[decimal_pos]
  mul ebx

  add eax, dword[number]
  mov dword[number], eax

  ; clear ebx and edx for multiplication
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor edx, edx
  xor eax, eax

  mov eax, dword[decimal_pos]
  mov ebx, 10
  mul ebx
  mov dword[decimal_pos], eax

  pop ebx

  dec ecx

  jmp .convert_dword_loop

.exit :
  mov eax, dword[number]
  pop ebp
  ret

;****************************
; returns the number of bytes
bytes_length : 
  push ebp

  ; get buffer address
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 8]
  mov eax, 0

.len_loop :
  cmp byte[ebx + eax], 0
  je .exit

  ; increment counter
  inc eax

  jmp .len_loop

.exit :
  pop ebp
  ret


;***************************************************
; ebp - 8 = passed number
; esp - 12 = count variable for storing the digit count
; eax = return of the count to caller
get_digit_count : 

  push ebp

  ; check if num is 0
  cmp dword[ebp - 8], 0
  je .num_is_zero

  ; allocate count variable on stack
  sub esp, 4
  mov dword[esp - 12], 0 ; count variable (count  = 0)

.dg_cnt_loop : 

  ; if num <= 0
  cmp dword[ebp - 8], 0
  jle .exit

  ; increment count 
  inc dword[esp - 12]

  ; clear eax, ebx and edx for division
  xor eax, eax
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor edx, edx

  ; num / 10
  mov eax, dword[ebp - 8]
  mov ebx, 10
  idiv ebx

  ; assign division result to num
  mov dword[ebp - 8], eax

  jmp .dg_cnt_loop

.num_is_zero : 
  ; if num is 0 then return 1
  mov eax, 1
  ; restore ebp
  pop ebp
  ret

.exit :
  ; assign count to eax
  mov eax, dword[esp - 12]
  ; restore allocated local variables
  add esp, 4
  ; restore ebp
  pop ebp
  ret

;******************************************************
; convert dword to array of bytes
; this function is same as itoa() in our C kernel code
; ebp - 8 = number
; ebp - 12 = address of byte array
; esp - 16 = digit_count variable
; esp - 20 = index variable
dword_to_byte_array : 

  push ebp

  ; allocate digit_count variable
  sub esp, 4
  mov dword[esp - 16], 0

  ; allocate index variable
  sub esp, 4
  mov dword[esp - 20], 0

  ; store the num value to ebx for temporary
  ; sometimes calling a function may lost the original value
  ; push the value in the stack
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 8]
  push ebx

  ; get digit count of num by calling get_digit_count
  mov eax, dword[ebp - 8]
  push eax
  call get_digit_count
  add esp, 4

  ; pop the original num value
  pop ebx
  ; assign it to variable
  mov dword[ebp - 8], ebx


  ; assign digit count to digit count variable
  mov dword[esp - 16], eax

  ; decrement digit count by 1 as index for byte array
  dec eax

  ; assign index as digit_count to index variable
  mov dword[esp - 20], eax

  ; if num <= 0
  cmp dword[ebp - 8], 0
  je .dwrd_to_bt_zero_num

  ; if num > 0
.convert_char_loop : 
  ; if num <= 0
  cmp dword[ebp - 8], 0
  jle .exit_convrt_char

  ; clear eax, ebx and edx for division
  xor eax, eax
  xor ebx, ebx
  xor edx, edx

  ; num / 10
  mov eax, dword[ebp - 8]
  mov ebx, 10
  idiv ebx

  ; assign division result to num
  mov dword[ebp - 8], eax

  ; convert digit to character
  add dl, 0x30  ; 0x30 = '0'

  ; assign converted character to array
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 12]  ; ebx = array address
  mov ecx, dword[esp - 20]  ; eax = index
  mov byte[ebx + ecx], dl   ; array[index] = char

  ; decrement index
  dec dword[esp - 20]

  jmp .convert_char_loop

.dwrd_to_bt_zero_num : 
  ; if digit count == 1
  cmp dword[esp - 16], 1
  je .digit_count_is_1

.digit_count_is_1 : 
  ; get array address
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 12]
  mov byte[ebx], 0x30 ; character '0'
  mov byte[ebx + 1], 0x00 ; null terminator
  jmp .exit

.exit_convrt_char : 
  ; get array address
  mov ebx, dword[ebp - 12]
  mov eax, dword[esp - 16]
  mov byte[ebx + eax], 0x00 ; null terminator
  jmp .exit

.exit :

  add esp, 8

  pop ebp
  ret

;*****************************************
; this function increase NEWLINE variable
; and set cursor position to it
print_new_line :
  push ebp

  inc byte[NEWLINE]

  mov ah, 0x02
  mov bh, 0x00
  mov dl, 0; x pos
  mov dh, byte[NEWLINE]
  int 0x10

  pop ebp
  ret


;********************************************
; this function sets the cursor position to 
; provided x,y coordinates
goto_xy : 
  push ebp

  mov ah, 0x02
    mov bh, 0x00
  mov dl, byte[ebp - 8]; x pos
    mov dh, byte[ebp - 12] ; y pos
    int 0x10

  pop ebp

  ret

;********************************
; clear the gloabl buffer BUFFER
clear_global_buffer :
  mov ecx, 0

.clr_buf_loop :
  cmp ecx, dword[BUFSIZE]
  je .exit

  mov byte[BUFFER + ecx], 0x00

  jmp .clr_buf_loop

.exit :
  ret


; x86 code end


;******************************************
; set the required disk space we need
  times (4096 - ($ - $$)) db 0x00


;******************************************
; data sections

;******************************************
; read only data section
section .rodata
  __STACK__ dd 0x00FFFFFF
  __HEAP__ dd 0x00008C24
  BUFSIZE dd 512

  ; key codes

  ENTER_KEY db 0x1C
  DELETE_KEY db 0x0E

  KEYCODE_1 db 0x02
  KEYCODE_2 db 0x03
  KEYCODE_3 db 0x04
  KEYCODE_4 db 0x05
  KEYCODE_5 db 0x06
  KEYCODE_6 db 0x07
  KEYCODE_7 db 0x08
  KEYCODE_8 db 0x09

;******************************************
; initialized data section
section .data
  number dd 0
  decimal_pos dd 0
  NEWLINE db 0

  X dd 0
  Y dd 0

  number_1 dd 0
  number_2 dd 0
  result   dd 0

  os_msg db '! 80x86 Operating System !', 0
  calc_msg db '[ x86 Calculator Program ]', 0
  menu_str db '!--- Menu ---!', 0
  addition_menu db '1] Addition', 0
  substraction_menu db '2] Substraction', 0
  multiplication_menu db '3] Multiplication', 0
  division_menu db '4] Division', 0
  modulus_menu db '5] Modulus', 0
  logicaland_menu db '6] Logical AND', 0
  logicalor_menu db '7] Logical OR', 0
  clear_screen_menu db '8] Clear Screen', 0
  select_choice_str db 'Enter your choice : ', 0
  invalid_choice_str db 'Invalid choice', 0
  error_msg db 'Error : Please enter only numerics', 0

  addition db 'Addition : ', 0
  substraction db 'Substraction : ', 0
  multiplication db 'Multiplication : ', 0
  division db 'Division : ', 0
  modulus db 'Modulus : ', 0
  logicaland db 'Logical AND : ', 0
  logicalor db 'Logical OR : ', 0

  enter_first_number db 'Enter first number : ', 0
  enter_second_number db 'Enter Second number : ', 0

  reload_screen_msg db 'Press any key to reload screen...', 0

;******************************************
; block started by symbol(bss) section
section .bss
  BUFFER resb 512
  choice resb 1
  KEYCODE resb 1
  KEYCHAR resb 1
;*******************************************
```

Comment: I don't think very many people are going to want to read 1400 lines of code to try to find your problem.  Can you create a [mcve], emphasis on "minimal"?  Have you tried using a debugger (e.g. in a virtual machine) to single-step your program through the problematic code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you've indicated by ";CALCULATOR CODE STARTS HERE" **is never loaded in memory**. You've mistakenly used the wrong function number!

```
; load third sector into memory
mov ah, 0x03                    ; load third stage to memory
```

The BIOS function number for loading is 02h, not 0x03 as you've written.

---

Even if the above were corrected will the code that follows reload those second and third sectors (16 in total) and jump to them. This will result in **an endless loop**...

> ```
> mov ah, 0x02
> mov al, 0x10
> mov dl, 0x80
> mov ch, 0              ;
> mov dh, 0              ;
> mov cl, 2              ; SAME AS BEFORE !!!!!!!!
> mov bx, _start
> int 0x13
> cli
> jmp _start
> ```